# Get context-root from sun-web.xml in web service

Tags: java, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

On deployment, the web service URL is http://localhost:8080/[context-root]/[serviceName]. The context-root is the notably the name of the project, but otherwise only shows up in sun-web.xml in WEB-INF.
How can I get this information to the java layer? I need to get the url of the web service programmatically and the context-root is the only piece of information missing right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do this. Assume this code in service class

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;

@WebMethod
public String myServiceOperation(){
MessageContext context = wsContext.getMessageContext();
HttpServletRequest res = (HttpServletRequest) context.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST) ;
System.out.println(" Context:path "+res.getContextPath());
}
```

This prints the context path to console.